# JaseperReports plugin for Netbeans classpath problem

Tags: java, netbeans, reporting, jasper-reports

I've installed the JasperReport 4.11 plugin for Netbeans (6.9.1). 
I've realized a simple bean like the following:

```
package jr;
import java.io.Serializable;
    public class Person implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private String lastname;

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    //all the other setters and getters

}
```

When i edit the report into the "Report Query" dialog (left click + right click on the background and chose "edit query"), into the panel JavaBean datasource i write the class name: 
jr.Person 
and I click on "Read attributes" 
i get the error:
"Class not found error!!
Controlla il tuo classpath e riprova!"
(the second part is localized in italian... translation: "check your classpath and try again")
It seems like the JasperReports plugin for Netbeans doesn't use the classpath of the project! (I have build the project, of course)
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right Agostino, the iReport plugin has it's own classpath and won't use the one of the project. Annoying isn't it!

You need to go to `Tools > Options` and then select `iReport` at the top. Click on the classpath tab and add all the neccessary libraries there. I'm not sure which libraries you will need for your report to work. I include `jasperreports-extensions-3.5.3.jar` and `hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar` in my classpath, but I'm using JasperReports 3.7.6 so I think it would be different in your case.

Comment: Ok, very helpful. But there are NOT the libraries that you've to include (they should already be in place). It starts to work when you add {project root}/build/classes. And this obviously has to be changed each project you work on.

Comment: Exactly, you need to compile the class files into a jar, and include that jar on the classpath.  See my response below.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the tool w/ the plugin and a java project setup.  But I know when I grab the standalone ireports I need to go the configurations and classpath and add the jar to classpath.  I would try to do something simliar.